# HTML Form Automation Using Ampersand (&) and Dollar Sign ($) Characters

Tags: forms

So I am trying to automate a basic HTML form I fill out a few times each day.  I am trying to open the web browser with the form completely filled out.  This is often a simple task, as the & character followed by the name of the form element and a value, usually works.  Where this becomes tricky is that my form elements have a placeholder that uses the $ character in its name.  The code is shown below:

```
 <input name="username" type="text" />
 <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$PasswordTextBox" type="password" 
     id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_PasswordTextBox" />
  <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Click" />
```

If you look at the name of the password tag you will see the use of the $ character twice.  Normally I could just type my URL into Chrome like the folowing:

```
 wwww.theWebSite.html&username=myName&ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$PasswordTextBox=myPassword
 &submit=Click
```

The above code would normally work but it doesn't in this case.  I don't know why I am getting the error but I think it is due to the use of the $ character.  All I am trying to do is load my page into the browser with the above form completely filled out.  Any ideas?

Comment: add your code ...

Comment: That is the code.  Just name of the form elements are "username", "password" and "Submit".  The ampersand should fill these out but it does not work when the name of the input type (password) is hidden.  I just want to save a url name with a form already filled out.  The tab key is useful for moving around forms in a website.  I was thinking the same functionality could be applied to my problem but I could be completely wrong.  I just want to use the ampersand to fill out my html form.

Comment: What do you mean when you say the name of the password is hidden? I don't understand what you mean by that. All form inputs should have a name. How do you want them filled out? You can use Javascript, PHP, etc...

Comment: Oh I think I understand. This not a site that you developed and you just want a way to automatically fill out the fields to make the site easier to use. Am I right?

Comment: There are actually two names.  One is hidden and the other uses the $ character in the name of form element.  The name of the one that is shown is ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$PasswordTextBox.  I think the $ character is causing the error for the one.

Comment: Correct Kodos, I just want to automate some basic processes.  I have some executable files that do this for many of my forms but a couple are creating some issues.